# It's possible read memory address without readprocessmemory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, c++14

It's possible read memory address without readprocessmemory same as dll injection:

Ex:

In dll injection:

```
int main()
{
  char SomeAnyValue = *(char*)0x00001; // address of sample
}
```

In an extern process I need the Handle process, Fine until now...
but is it possible read the value like in dll injection without using of readprocessmemory?

Edit:
The original question was about if it was possible to read memory from any process remotely without an handle or dynamic link library injected on it. Has been some years since I made the question. To clarify I solved the problem using an driver and yeah, it is possible.

Comment: That's not actually defined within the c++ standard.

Comment: Not possible since ReadProcessMemory reads other process memory, and your process operates within its own defined memory range, having no access to other process' memory.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Thx for the answer, just wanted an answer from someone who already would have had experience in this, i don' t know why many negatives, and another who answered me nonsense.

Comment: No one has answered at all yet, and @πάνταῥεῖ's _comment_ is not nonsense – you've asked a question and tagged it `c++`, while it has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Is your question how to share memory between two processes? Are you wanting to read memory from a process that you build (can you influence the process design)? Do you want the process handle of a second process?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL injection works by *injecting code into the target process*!  Once the code has been injected, it runs in the address space of the target process, and as such has direct access to the target process's memory addresses.

If you do not inject your code into the target process, it *does not have direct access* to the target process's address space, and as such it must use `ReadProcessMemory()` instead.

Comment: Unless the two processes use shared memory... Or mapped memory... Or a data item exported from a dll designed to be shared...

Comment: With shared memory, you are not actually accessing the target process's memory *directly*, you are both accessing local memory that has been mapped to the same pagefile.

Comment: On Windows, each process has page table entries that point to the same physical memory. They are indeed accessing the same physical memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you have answered what I wanted to know thx, and for others not bad raised the question, which no  have previous experience with this does not mean this badly formulated.